# Toolbar in the wrong location on BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm building an app and when I load the view with the `BottomNavigationView`, I have odd issues all the time, sometimes, I have an extra space and other times, the toolbar is wrongly located, for example:

**With bottom navigation:**

[image: bottomnavigation]

**Without bottom navigation:**

[image: no bottom navigation]

This is my code for the 1st image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
        <include
            layout="@menu/toolbar_recipe" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_recipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

And this is how it behaves with the `CoordinatorLayout`, after I set the paddingTop as `?attr/actionBarSize` the `FrameLayout` moved some space, but it's still wrongly located.

[image: odd space]

**With CoordinatorLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">
        <include
            layout="@menu/toolbar_recipe" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Without that addition, it just stays behind. I'm working in Android 8+, but I don't think it's the issue and I'm out of ideas how to coordinate that situation. Has anyone experienced it?

Thanks for any comment, especially of why it's happening since I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on this line:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

I needed to add it to the root element more or less like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

And here is a description of the property:

> System windows are the parts of the screen where the system is drawing
>   either non-interactive (in the case of the status bar) or interactive
>   (in the case of the navigation bar) content.
>
> Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or
>   the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive
>   elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the
>   default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute
>   gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents
>   don’t overlay the system windows.

I found it here:

[Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec)